# stompest not sending ack until python interpreter exits

Tags: python, rabbitmq, stomp, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I have a rabbitmq queue running on its own server.

I can do `sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues` on this server to the number of messages on the queue.

On another server I receive 10 frames, and acknowledge them. I then check the number of messages on the queue and the number has not changed.

I then close the python interpreter and check the number of messages on the queue server, and the number has reduced by the expected amount (10). I can repeat this process many times and the same behaviour occurs.

If this is as per design, how can I make the ack happen immediately? I thought maybe there is odd behaviour in **del** method of the client class, but [nope](https://github.com/nikipore/stompest/blob/master/src/core/stompest/sync/client.py).

Is there some undocumented magic happening?

My "acking" code:

```
client = Stomp(StompConfig(uri=settings.QUEUE_SERVER))
client.connect()
client.subscribe(
    settings.INBOUND_QUEUE_NAME,
    {StompSpec.ACK_HEADER: StompSpec.ACK_CLIENT_INDIVIDUAL}
)

for each in range(10):
    frame = self.client.receiveFrame()
    self.client.ack(frame)
```

Comment: This is not the expected behavior. Please show the code with with which you are "acking". probably something there..

Comment: @alonisser I have added my code

Comment: @rikAtree. sorry I missed that you aren't using ampq protocol directly but this (stomp) varient of it.. So I can't be sure this isn't a designated behavior (Also not very reasonable)..

Comment: Looking at the client code everything seems reasonable. I suspect it's a poor default/incorrect transaction scoping somewhere but nothing immediately stands out.Please report this to rabbitmq-discuss (https://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rabbitmq-discuss), we'll file a bug to investigate.

Comment: will do. It will be hard to provide follow up info and do experiments because I've removed stomp from my stack given this problem. I switched over to using plain old vanilla rabbitmq without stomp plugin, and pika python module.